# Reading deployed contract state in Python

Tags: contract-development, json-rpc, python

I'd like to monitor (or poll or just do one off reads in the first place) a contract I deploy in the Ethereum network from a Python server-side application. Specifically it's a modified standard token contract deployed by me and I'd like to now and then check the status of accounts.

- What options I have: Interacting via RPC with geth (using ethjsonrpc https://github.com/ConsenSys/ethjsonrpc) or any API services?
- I'd like to read the current contract state variables - how do I can get access to current state variables over RPC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you effectively can use [ethjsonrpc](https://github.com/ConsenSys/ethjsonrpc) which implements the 62 methods

you can also try to look at [populus](https://github.com/pipermerriam/populus) and what it brings :

- [testing stuff](http://populus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/populus.testing-fixtures.html)
  especially the ipc client which may be an alternative if you prefer dealing with the socket.
- [interact with contracts](http://populus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/populus.contracts.html) , that's probably what you dreamt of ;)

Comment: Looks nice! I did not spot an example to initialize contract from address & ABI (JSON)... but it's there somewhere?

Comment: http://populus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/populus.contracts.html#contractclass-address-rpc-client ?